# How to identify the blocked Google extension and remove it from the OS?

Tags: macos, catalina, kernel-extensions

When I rebooted my MBP (Catalina), I got this error message

[image]

When I jumped into the System Preferences, this is what I see

[image]

It does not give me a lot of information where the extension comes from.

How can I identify which extension it is? If I can identify it, then I will know if I still need it or not.

Comment: Issue the command `sudo spctl --list` and see if you can see which Google App got denied.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328141/how-to-identify-extensions-blocked-by-gatekeeper?rq=1 Please check this post too. It's old, for high Sierra, but some answers are more generic than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an easy way to identify which kernel extension is causing this MacOS blocking of its install.

When you are on the `Security & Privacy` `System Preferences…` telling you:

```
System software from developer "Google, Inc." was blocked
from loading.
```

just select <kbd>Allow</kbd> once just to be able to get its real name and not to keep it installed.

Then let the complete boot of MacOS terminate, and open a `Terminal` or `xterm`.

Enter the following command to extract from all your kernel extensions the one which developer might be Google with:

```
/usr/bin/sudo kextstat | egrep -i '(^Index|google)'
```

The 6th field of output of this command is the bundle name under which this extension is registered in the MacOS kernel.
Let's say for this example its name is:

```
com.google.kext.foo
```

Next go to:

```
cd /Library/Extensions
```

and search for this bundle name within all the Google looking directories:

```
grep 'com.google.kext.foo' [gG]oogle*/Contents/Info.plist
```

Then if Google made its job of developer correctly you should be able to find on the web what this extension id doing.

And you will know if you need it or not.

If you want to keep it within your `/Library/Extensions` but not loaded within MacOS, just `reboot`.

Investigation closed.

Comment: In my case it is a `com.google.santa-driver`. Thx for your answer.

Comment: Coming from: https://github.com/google/santa . Thank you for your return which might be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1):

Having spent some time with Google, the only reference I see to a kernel extension is Google File Stream.

- https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/27765/google-file-stream-team-id
- https://macadmins.co.il/2019/01/21/macos-security-secure-kernel-extension-loading-skel/

This would make sense, as Dropbox also wants to install a kernel extension for what it does. I believe Dropbox’s “Smart Sync” feature requires it, and I believe Google has a similar feature for what used to be called “Google Drive”.

However, if you do not use Smart Sync with Dropbox, you don’t need the kernel extension.

Unfortunately I don’t know enough about Google File Stream to know what features might rely on the kernel extension, but perhaps this will give you a start in looking for more information.